# Geometric construction exercises

Tags: mathematics-education, mathematical-software, geometric-constructions, software

Many of you know dynamic geometry exercises in [Euclidea](https://www.euclidea.xyz/en/); if not, here is [one example](https://www.euclidea.xyz/en/game/11.5).
It lets you do a geometric construction and sends a message once you achieve the result.

I am looking for a way to produce exercises for students in a similar form.
At the moment I use [C.a.R.](http://car.rene-grothmann.de/doc_en/index.html) which uses Java plugins.
But as you may know, all major browsers stopped supporting Java plugins in 2014 or so.
So I [have to make my students install JDK (or OpenJDK)](https://anton-petrunin.github.io/birkhoff/car/index.html) which is not fun.

There is plenty of software that does dynamic geometry, but as far as I see nothing else has the exercise mode that I need; **or did I miss something?**

Comment: This seems like a better fit for [MESE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @LSpice I think there is a better chance to get an answer here (but I agree it does not fit perfectly in MO).